# Blank table when exporting a feature selection of a image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, reflectance

I'm trying to get reflectance data of some points that i've gotten from another database through a Json table of pings.

I've used this code to get the data but returns only the title of columns with null reflectance values:

```
var rrs = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI")
  .filterDate('2018-1-04', '2018-1-05')
  .select('Rrs_645', 'Rrs_555', 'Rrs_443')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

var reduceR = function(image) {
  return image.set(image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: geometry,
 }));
};

var mRrs=rrs.map(reduceR);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: mRrs, 
  description: 'rrs', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'rrs', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV', 
  selectors: ['Rrs_645', 'Rrs_555','Rrs_443']
});
```

Thannnks

Comment: what (where) is `geometry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are mapping over an image collection which returns an image collection object not a feature collection. Plus within your mapping function, you are returning an image object with the reduced data set in its properties.

Since we essentially want to convert each image to a feature with reduced data as columns, the first step would be to convert it to a list of images and map that list to process each image.

I don't have your geometry so i added a point of my own and came up with something like this.

```
rrs = rrs.toList(rrs.size());

var reduceR = function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image);
  var reducedVal = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: geometry,
  })
  return ee.Feature(geometry).set(reducedVal);
};

var mRrs=rrs.map(reduceR);
mRrs = ee.FeatureCollection(mRrs);
```

Rest of the code remains same. You can view a working script [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cce4fe53f6bf3912ce8338fd080e7fc5)

Comment: Very very very thank u !!!!!!!!!! Super works !